# Getting Error <location allowOverride="false"> while hosting WEB API 2 in Hostgator

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, hosting, web-hosting

I am using WEB API 2 its working in my local system,but when  WEB API 2 run in Hostgator windows server its given me error below is my error screenshot

http://prntscr.com/bc5ihv

Comment: What are you expecting to see (i.e. What do you see in localhost?)

Comment: mydomain.com/api/contoller/action,i should get this

Comment: @kittysarvaj Were you able to resolve that ? I have same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, I got similar problem while hosting web api on shared hosting. 
The solution is to remove `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` package and **clean and build**

> You can deploy even without Roslyn with no change in code. Open NuGet Package Manager window and uninstall Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform package and rebuild & republish. This uninstallation also removes CodeDom configuration from web.config file. This will solve your purpose. Basically this will not generate any csc.exe, vbc.exe files inside bin folder.

I got it from [here](http://www.itorian.com/2015/09/roslyn-cscexe-and-vbcexe-deployment-on.html)