# How to use Web API with HostGator Windows shared plan?

Tags: .net, windows, asp.net-web-api, shared-hosting

I have a shared plan on [HostGator](http://www.hostgator.com). I would like to create Web API services on my site, but it crashes because of security issues:

Url:

```
http://example.com/api/welcome/Mitulat
```

Code:

```
// GET api/welcome/5
public string Get(string id)
{
    return "Hello " + id + "!";
}
```

web.config file:

```
 <system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
 </system.web>
```

Locally it works, but when I upload it to the server the page says:

> **Description**: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> **Exception Details**: `System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.`

The support said the application must be published with medium trust level, so I added this line to the `<system.web>` section of the `web.config` file:

```
<trust level="Medium"/>
```

Now the page says:

> **Description**: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message**: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access
>   to this section using `<location allowOverride="false">` from an
>   inherited configuration file.

**The support said I shouldn't use this feature.** Could it be true? I mean HostGator serves millions of web pages. I bet some of them use Web API...
I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 days of research, 3 more conversation with the "support", and a nervous breakdown I successfully managed to execute Web API requests in the Hostgator shared plan based on this question.

[Getting Error <location allowOverride="false"> while hosting WEB API 2 in Hostgator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37627074/2183775)

Without this I don't know what I would've done...

Brief:

> You can deploy even without Roslyn with no change in code. Open NuGet Package Manager window and uninstall Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform package and rebuild & republish. This uninstallation also removes CodeDom configuration from web.config file. This will solve your purpose. Basically this will not generate any csc.exe, vbc.exe files inside bin folder.